# Servicestack : From route to operation

Tags: servicestack

Can I retrieve the operation DTO from url route inside a service stack service ?

Example :

```
public class HelloService : IService
{

    public object Any(HelloRequest request)
    {
//Here I want to retrieve operation Dto. 
//In this case if request.AnotherApiRoute is "/another?Age=33" 
//then result could be operation AnotherRequest 

       return new HelloResponse { Result = "Hello, " + name };
    }
}

public class AnotherApiService : IService
{
      public object Another(AnotherRequest request)
      {
            return new AnotherResponse { Result = "Your Age : " + Age };
      }
}
```

//OPERATIONS

```
[Route("/hello/{Name}")]
public class Hello : IReturn<HelloResponse>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AnotherApiRoute {get; set;}
}

public class HelloResponse
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
}

[Route("/another/{Age}")]
public class AnotherRequest : IReturn<AnotherResponse>
{
    public string Age { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherResponse
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for your suggests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want access to the HTTP Request Context the Service was executed in you should inherit from the convenience `Service` base class (or have your service also implement `IRequiresRequestContext` so Request is injected), e.g:

```
public class HelloService : Service
{
    public object Any(Hello request)
    {
       var pathInfo = base.Request.PathInfo;
       return new HelloResponse { Result = "Hello, " + name };
    }
}
```

But what you're after is unclear since the Request DTO **is** the Operation DTO for that request. If instead you wanted to call another Service from within your Service you can do it with Resolving the Service from the IOC (which also injects the current HTTP Request) with:

```
public class HelloService : Service
{
    public object Any(Hello request)
    {
        using (var service = base.ResolveService<AnotherService>())
        {
            var anotherDto = request.ConvertTo<Another>();
            return service.Any(anotherDto);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can just execute the Service by passing in the Request DTO, and let ServiceStack call the appropriate Service, e.g:

```
public class HelloService : Service
{
    public object Any(Hello request)
    {
        var anotherDto = request.ConvertTo<Another>();
        return base.ExecuteRequest(anotherDto);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mythz for your answer.